# On theme change activity and dialogue fragments is crash show error dialog fragments is not associated with fragments manager

Tags: android, mobile, android-activity, crash, themes

Can anyone face these issues or know about that. You can show fragments on main activity by using transaction but during that when we processing with API then we show dialog fragments during processing of API user change app theme from mobile setting notification then app is crash because activity is re-create due to theme change then that loader dialogue is through crash support fragment manager is not associated with fragments

I use fragments transaction and dialogue fragments on main activity by using fragments container view.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.